# the contents of a div clip outside of it's boundaries

Tags: css

I have a div here with a bunch of buttons inside and this CSS code:

```
#shop {
  height:calc(45% - 15px);
  overflow:scrollable;
}
```

however, the overflow will not work properly. Despite the fixed height, the buttons always spill out underneath. Ideally, this would instead be something you are able to scroll through. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/38d1rc06/1/

edit: this is embarrassing, but my issue was I had typed "scrollable" instead of "scroll" in regards to the overflow - sorry about that!

Comment: The value should be `scroll` and not `scrollable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For begin - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow
Use a `scroll`, but not "scrollable".

And second peace inner content do not wrap - `#shop {white-space: nowrap}`.